# How to force Scanner to read unfinished line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with last line of input. I cannot force Scanner to read a number from last line since it is unfinished. When I copy input with one more line after the previous last line, there is no problem, but i cannot have the extra line there.

[Link to problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3811)

Example of input:

```
2  
1 1  
9 9  
4   
4 5  
6 5  
2 5  
3 4  

-1
```

I've tried `sc.nextInt()`, `sc.next()`, `sc.nextLine()` and nothing can reach the `-1`. Even `sc.hasNext`, `sc.hasNextInt` etc. are waiting.

```
while(true)
    {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(line);
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }

        if(a == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        rr = new int[a][2];

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            numbers = line.split(" ");

            try {
                rr[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
                rr[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }

        }

        b = sc.nextInt();

        sc.nextLine();

        tt = new int[b][2];

        for(int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            numbers = line.split(" ");

            try {
                tt[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
                tt[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }

        }
        sc.nextLine();

    }
```

Comment: Read all lines with nextLine. Parse the Integer(s) as a secondary step

Comment: tried, unfortunately it didnt work... probably it waits for line ending or something

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java should help

Comment: Here you are ^^

Comment: Maybe try `sc.setDelimiter("\\s|$")` so it'll catch the end of the string.

Comment: Didn't help... It works on my pc now but UVA Online Judge will not take it

Comment: You want a `continue` within the catch statements. Also, not really clear what the `b` value is supposed to be.

Comment: it does not really matter since any exception means fail... b means number of something, I need it to make a field of preffered size

Comment: When you read the blank line then call `parseInt(line)`, it'll throw `NumberFormatException`, but since you catch **and ignore** the exception, what value do you think `a` has? *(Hint: It's unchanged)*.

Comment: Post the link to the problem statement

Comment: Problem itself is easy, I have problem with validation :D https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3811

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true) {
    // read the line.. 
    line = sc.nextLine().trim();
    // check if it's a blank line...
    // blank line means new test case.. Take the value of n
    if (line.length() == 0) line = sc.nextLine().trim();

    // now parse the value of n.. If it's -1 then end of input
    a = Integer.parseInt(line);
    if (a==-1) break;

    // rest of your input
}
```

Take the value of `b` like this:

```
b = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().trim());
```

And remove the 'extra' `sc.nextLine()`from below of `b` and from the bottom of while loop. That case is handled at the top.

Comment: Doesnt work neither. I tried to debug it and it stucks on the if(line.length() == 0) line = sc.nextLine();

Comment: Use these sites:  http://uhunt.felix-halim.net/id/377362   https://www.udebug.com/UVa/12389   I have edited my answer. You need to probably trim the strings before you parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to get the -1 you could have a separate scanner use the delimiter /n (line break) and have it delete the extra break between -1 and the last line before it. Then you could go through and just scan with .nextLine() or .nextInt().

Comment: Isnt it the same what does .nextLine() on the same place?

Comment: .nextLine() will return whatever is on the next line. What I am proposing is to set up a scanner so that it searches for blank lines, and then edits the file so that it contains no blank lines. After that, it goes through and gets the integers you want, and should have no problem getting -1 since it will no longer have an empty line separating it from the other numbers.